# any_cast with std::any's and std::optional

Tags: c++, option-type, std, c++17, stdany

If I put a `T` into an `std::any`, I can get it with `any_cast<T>(my_any)`. But does the standard (= C++17, in the ballot phase at the moment) include a function like `any_cast<T>(optional<any> oa)` which returns `nullopt` if oa is `nullopt` and `std::any_cast<T>(oa.value())` otherwise? Or something along those lines?

**Edit:** Since people seem to be suggesting implementations, I'll also list what I use for now:

```
/* using magic here to select between boost/std::experimental/std versions */

template<typename T>
inline const optional<T> any_cast(const optional<any>& operand)
{
    return operand ? 
        optional<T>(any_cast<T>(operand.value())) :
        optional<T>(nullopt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of anything like that in the [`std::optional` proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html) or in the [`std::any` proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3804.html).

I suppose it would be trivial to implement using a continuation function, since the return type is different depending on the state of the optional object:

```
template <typename T, typename TOptional, typename TF>
void any_cast_or_nullopt(TOptional&& o, TF&& f)
{
    if(!o) return; 
    f(std::any_cast<T>(*o));
}
```

Add `static_assert` and/or *SFINAE* where appropriate to constrain the function. The value `*o` should also be forwarded depending on `o`'s value category. Example usage:

```
int out = -1;

std::optional<std::any> x;
x = 10;

any_cast_or_nullopt<int>(x, [&out](int value)
    {
        out = value;
    });

assert(out == 10);
```

Comment: I like your suggestion, but do you really need 3 template arguments?

Comment: If you want correctness and flexibility, yes: `T` is used for the `any_cast`; `TOptional` is used to perfect-forward the optional's value; `TF` is used for a generic callable object. You could implement it without `TOptional`, but  you will require code repetition in order to correctly move `*o` when `o` is passed as an r-value.

Comment: But I don't have an f. You're forcing me to combine the casting with the use of its result - which is not like any cast.

Comment: @einpoklum: you asked for a function that given an `optional<any>` and a template parameter `T` returns either a `T` instance or `nullopt` - this is impossible because `T` and `nullopt_t` are unrelated types and because the state of the `optional` is only known at run-time. You can either have your function return an `optional<T>` *(as Barry suggested)*, or use a continuation function in order to directly use the `T` as I suggested.

Comment: Of course the function should returns an optional<T>, that's what I meant by returning either a T or a nullopt... but ok, I see why you've done what you did. You've essentially implemented an `and_then`.

Answer (score 0):

If `std::optional` had a `bind` (or [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then)) member function (that is, a function on `optional<T>` which takes a `T -> optional<U>` and either invokes it or returns `nullopt`), then that's what you'd be looking for:

```
std::optional<std::any>> oa;

optional<T> opt_t = oa.bind([](std::any& v) -> std::optional<T> {
    if (T* t = std::any_cast<T>(&v)) {
        return *t;
    }
    else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
});
```

or, if you really want to directly invoke `any_cast<T>` and deal with throwing, `map`:

```
optional<T> opt_t = oa.map([](std::any& v) {
    return std::any_cast<T>(v);
});
```

`std::optional` has no continuation functions though, so you'd have to write those as non-member functions.